# Why isn't this sublime text keybind working?

Tags: sublimetext2

```
{
    "keys": ["control+shift+a"], "command": "align_tab",
    "args" : {"user_input" : ":/f"}
}
```

I'm attempting to bind `Control+Shift+A` to the "align colons" command of the SublimeText plugin "AlignTab"... but this keybind isn't working, despite it being a near copy paste of what's in their tutorial.

Anyone have any idea? What am I doing wrong?

Reference: https://github.com/randy3k/AlignTab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `Ctrl+Shift+A` might already be bound to another command. In my default keybinds file, it shows that:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+a"], "command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "tag"} },
```

Other than that, your syntax checks out, so I'm not sure how that could break.

Comment: I removed that line from key bindings - default and now the only ctrl+shift+a hotkey in any of my keybindings files is the one above... and it still wont work :(

Comment: Yeah, i'm not sure how sublimetext deals with conflicting keybindings. but if it works, it works! :D

Comment: Check out [Merging and Order of Precedence](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/packages.html#merging-and-order-of-precedence) in the docs for details. Basically, since the `Packages/User` folder is at the end of the list, any `.sublime-keymap` file there is read _last_, and therefore overrides the defaults. The default keymap (or any preferences file) should never be edited, as changes will be lost on update. Instead, make a file of the same name in the `User` folder, with only the options you want to change, and you should be all set.